# Horizontal divider with Text inserted

Tags: css, html

I'm hoping someone could help me out! I'm trying to achieve the desired effect seen on this wordpress template from themeforest (http://themeforest.net/item/lespaul-retina-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/4083224 -- scroll right down to the bottom).

Basically having a pixel divider repeat across the page, and have text embedded on the left side. I've tried SOOO many different CSS codes and html... It should be an easy thing to do but I just can't seem to get it.

The closest I've gotten a to achieve this effect is the horizontal divider with Text under it...

/////////////////////////////

TEXT(but centered)

but I would like to have

TEXT ///////////////////////////

Here's my code!

```
div.divider17a {
height:5px; width:100%; border:0; background:url(images/divider17.png) repeat-x;
margin:35px 0 25px;
padding:0;
text-align:left;
float:left;
width:100%;
}
div.divider_notext {
margin:50px 0 20px;
}
div.divider_left1 {
text-align:left;
}
```

HTML

`<div class="divider17a divider_left1"><h3>Strategic Planning</h3></div>`

Any help would be much appreciated... Thanks =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a link to your page and subsequent code? Also if you look at their code this is what they are doing:

```
.separator-heading, hr.diagonal {
background-image: url(../img/separator-heading-diagonal.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 0 50%;
```

}

Comment: Thanks!! I actually tried this, but it didnt work... Tried it again, and it did hehe =) Thank you =D

Comment: Glad it worked. Make sure you upvote and mark as a correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not just using the same styling they use anyway?

```
<h3 class="widget-heading separator-heading">
    <span class="text-holder">Companies that trust us</span>
</h3>

.separator-heading {
    background-image: url(../img/separator-heading-diagonal.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 50%;
}

.separator-heading .text-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .6em 0 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **have to** use text you can use the following CSS style:

```
.divider17a h3:after{
    content:"//////////////////////////////////////";
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and add the following to you container:

```
div.divider17a{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kyBaN/1/

Alternatively, use a background image.